# Heroku API for one-off dynos? similar to FaaS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a canonical pattern for triggering a heroku task through an api?

Basically I would like to trigger a rake task on a one-off dyno.

Seems like most people just implement background jobs with autoscaling for this:

1. creating a background job
2. counting the number of jobs in the queue
3. if count is greater than 0, scale workers to 1
4. if count is zero, scale workers to zero

sweeping every X minutes with scheduler to make sure that workers are activated in case steps 2,3,4 have errors.

- https://github.com/markquezada/heroku-resque-auto-scale
- https://github.com/heroku/platform-api